# How do you hide the _static directory from Sphinx's search index in a Python project?

Tags: python, python-sphinx

In a Sphinx project, how does one prevent documents in the _static directory of the project from appearing in the project search results?

Answer (score 3):

There is no configuration option for excluding files in a particular directory from the search index.

However, you can do it by modifying the [`IndexBuilder.feed()`](https://bitbucket.org/birkenfeld/sphinx/src/tip/sphinx/search/__init__.py) method. One of the arguments to this method is `doctree` (an instance of the Docutils `document` class). The path to the .rst document being processed is the value of `doctree.attributes['source']`.

Add the following monkey patch to **conf.py**:

```
from sphinx.search import IndexBuilder, WordCollector

def feed(self, filename, title, doctree):
    """Feed a doctree to the index."""

    # Patch: if '_static' is in the path, don't use the file to 
    # populate the search index
    source = doctree.attributes["source"]
    if "_static" in source:
        return

    self._titles[filename] = title

    visitor = WordCollector(doctree, self.lang)
    doctree.walk(visitor)

    def add_term(word, stem=self.lang.stem):
        word = stem(word)
        if self.lang.word_filter(word):
            self._mapping.setdefault(word, set()).add(filename)

    for word in self.lang.split(title):
        add_term(word)

    for word in visitor.found_words:
        add_term(word)

IndexBuilder.feed = feed
```

Tested with Sphinx 1.1.3.

Comment: There have been many changes to the source code since this answer was posted. See https://github.com/sphinx-doc/sphinx/blob/master/sphinx/search/__init__.py.

Comment: The `IndexBuilder` class is still there, but I suspect that the monkey patch needs to be updated in order to work with newer versions of Sphinx.